# Default Value does not work with DateTime and Fluent Nhibernate 1.2?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have datetime column and I want to put a default value if none is provided.

So in my fluent mapping I did

```
   Map(x => x.EndOfTerm).Default("5/21/2011").Not.Nullable();
```

Yet everytime I try to save something without a EndOfTerm specified it crashes

```
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

When I give EndOfTerm a value it does not crash anymore.

Comment: I don't think `Default` does what you think it does.

Comment: @ Diego Mijelshon - Um does it not set a default value when none is given? I been using it other places like that and it seems to work as I expected too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The insert="false" update="false" prevents NHibernate from using that field in INSERT and UPDATE statements, thereby forcing the database to generate the default value ([Ref.](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property)). 
So we have:

```
Map(x => x.EndOfTerm).Default("5/21/2011").Not.Nullable().Not.Insert().Not.Update().Generated.Always();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want to use **DynamicUpdate()** and **DynamicInsert()** in your ClassMaps if you want to use default values specified in your database for properties you have not set.  If you don't use either of these NHibernate will try to update/insert all columns regardless if they are dirty or not. Below is taken from NHibernate documentation.

(7)  **dynamic-update** (optional, defaults to false): Specifies that UPDATE SQL should be generated at runtime and contain only those columns whose values have changed.

(8)  **dynamic-insert** (optional, defaults to false): Specifies that INSERT SQL should be generated at runtime and contain only the columns whose values are not null.